# Deleting blank lines in faceted plot produced using geom_tile function from plotnine

Tags: python, heatmap, plotnine

Hi I'm trying to produce a facetted plot using the geom_tile function of the plotnine Python library. I'm getting stuck with blank lines that appear in classes A,B and C (see example below). I would like to delete these blank lines while preserving only objects/rows that belong to each of the classes.
Any idea is welcome.
Best

```
from plotnine import (ggplot, aes, geom_tile, 
                        facet_grid, theme_bw, 
                        scale_fill_gradientn, 
                        theme,
                        element_blank,
                        element_rect)
import plotnine
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
from pandas import Categorical


# Load the data.frame
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dputhier/dp_examples/master/plotnine/df_example_2.txt"
s= requests.get(url).content
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')), sep="\t", header=0)
data = data.sort_values("cls")
data.object = Categorical(data.object, categories=data.object.unique(), ordered=True)
data.condition = Categorical(data.condition, categories=data.condition.unique(), ordered=True)
data.cls = Categorical(data.cls, categories=data.cls.unique(), ordered=True)

# Create a facetted diagram

color_palette = "#d73027,#fc8d59,#fee090,#e0f3f8,#91bfdb,#253494"
color_palette_list = color_palette.split(",")

p = ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes('pos',
                                  'object')
                                  ) + geom_tile(aes(fill='value'))
p += theme_bw()
p += scale_fill_gradientn(colors=color_palette_list,
                          name="Signal", na_value="#222222")

p += plotnine.labels.xlab('position')
p += plotnine.labels.ylab("object")

p += theme(panel_grid_major=element_blank(),
           panel_grid_minor=element_blank(),
           panel_border=element_rect(colour="black", size=1))

p +=  plotnine.facet_grid("cls~condition ",
                          scales="free_y",
                          space="free")

p.save(filename='plot_dp.pdf')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this was a bug (#154) fixed using

pip install git+https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine.git